# How to get the hub status, i.e., to determine whether its running any tests or not?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

We have the grid console to check whether the nodes status, whether it is running any tests or not. So, if there is any other way to get the status of the hub, to determine if its being used or no?

Actual reason for getting this is to create a job to do a clean up/restart of the hub and node machines.

PS: I did some search, but i couldn't get any way around as of now.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to be building a custom servlet for this.

Assuming that your grid is running on `localhost` and is listening on port `4444` if you invoke the URL `http://localhost:4444/grid/api/hub` (GET operation), you should see a JSON response as below

```
{
   "success":true,
   "capabilityMatcher":"org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
   "newSessionWaitTimeout":-1,
   "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent":true,
   "cleanUpCycle":5000,
   "custom":{

   },
   "host":"localhost",
   "maxSession":1,
   "servlets":[

   ],
   "browserTimeout":0,
   "debug":false,
   "jettyMaxThreads":-1,
   "port":4444,
   "role":"hub",
   "timeout":1800,
   "newSessionRequestCount":0,
   "slotCounts":{
      "free":0,
      "total":0
   }
}
```

In the above JSON response, if you parse the values of `free` and `total` you should be able to get what you need. For e.g., if the values of `free` is equal to the value of `total` then it means there are no new sessions running.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link - http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp -- go to the "Adding custom servlets at the hub and/or node" section.

You can run customized servlets extending `org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistryBasedServlet` which will give you the information. This servlet has the `Registry` object getter method `getRegistry()`.

The Registry object has a `getActiveSessions()` method which returns a collection of tests currently running. You can check the size etc for your requirements.

Look at the selenium source code in the org.openqa.grid.web package, there are lots of servlets already coded.